# "element click intercepted" only on TFS

Tags: selenium, tfs, selenium-chromedriver, vstest

I have about 130 Selenium UI tests for a web app we're currently developing.

The problem I have is, whenever I run the tests locally through Visual Studio's test explorer (vstest), I have never encountered this error before.
The problem is, some of the tests keep failing due to this message when the tests are run on TFS (using vstest on TFS too). `element click intercepted`

I'm also 100% sure there is no overlaying element that interferes with the click method as the tests never fail with that message when run locally.

Any idea what could this be?

Comment: It could be that the page loads faster when running the tests locally as compared to when running from TFS. Try adding [explicit waits](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

Comment: It could also be caused by the browser viewport being a smaller size when running tests in TFS. Can you post the code you use to initialize the web driver for a TFS test run?

Comment: I'll try with this
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
That's my local window size

Comment: Hi miramarska, any update on this issue? Did you get a chance to implement the solution that  Greg Burghardt suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 3):

I had issues where all of my local tests would pass, but I would receive random errors as you mentioned when running the tests through Jenkins or TFS, usually errors indicating that my elements were not clickable, etc. - the issue ended up being the browser size.

I started running my test in headless mode and specified a large browser size. Switching to `--headless` and setting a browser size ended up solving most of my issues for me:

```
var headlessOptions = new ChromeOptions();
headlessOptions.AddArgument("--headless");
headlessOptions.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
headlessOptions.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1200");
```

You will have to use `--headless` for this to work too. I tried to run my tests by ONLY setting window size, but the tests would still fail anyway because the resolution of the virtual machines was not large enough to handle the browser size I had set.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by using 2 methods.
1.Running chrome in headless mode
2.Scorlling to the element before clicking or interacting with it

The root cause of this issue is due to the fact that the browser does not load with a browser size as that of browser when tested locally

If you intend to run the test in non headless mode you can use the following code to achieve the result.

```
IWebElement element= driver.FindElement(By.Id(selector));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while executing tests through a pipeline on VM. But the tests were executing properly on my local machine.

The issue was that the resolution of my local machine was 1920 X 1040, while that on the VM was 1040 X 780.

I added a piece of code to take a screenshot and identified this issue. Another element was found to overlay on my desired element, so there was no way to click on it.

I used `IJavaScriptExecutor` to click the desired element and was able to resolve this issue. Hope this helps. Cheers!